# show next expression when keypad_hash is pressed two times

Tags: android

I want to display a next expression when keypad_hash is pressed twice.

What I am able to do at the moment is:

- display "correct" when the answer is right when the keypad_hash is pressed once which is alright
- when I press keypad_hash again it doesn't do any anything

If my observation is right "click=1" in the first IF station is not doing anything.

```
if ("2+3=5".equals(display.getText().toString()))
        {
            correct.setText("CORRECT");
            click=1;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

---

```
package org.example.question;

import java.util.Random;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    //variable for different questions
    int fnum0, snum0,fnum1, snum1,fnum2, snum2,fnum3, snum3,
    fnum4, snum4,fnum5, snum5,fnum6, snum6,fnum7, snum7,
    fnum8, snum8,fnum9, snum9, answer;


    //variable and type declaration for buttons and text
Button keyOne;
Button keyTwo;
Button keyThree;
Button keyFour;
Button keyFive;
Button keySix;
Button keySeven;
Button keyEight;
Button keyNine;
Button keyDel;
Button keyZero;
Button keyHash;
Button keySubtract;
TextView display;
TextView display1;
TextView correct;
TextView Incorrect;
int q=0;
int click=0;





    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

        //display text on screen

        display1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Guess);
        display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);



        correct= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.CORRECT);
        Incorrect= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.INCORRECT);




        //assigning names to each keypad
        keyOne= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_1);
        keyTwo= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_2);
        keyThree= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_3);
        keyFour= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_4);
        keyFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_5);
        keySix= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_6);
        keySeven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_7);
        keyEight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_8);
        keyNine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_9);
        keyZero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_0);
        keySubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_subtract);
        keyHash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_hash);
        keyDel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);

        //setting button to produce an event when each button is pressed
        keyOne.setOnClickListener(this);     keyTwo.setOnClickListener(this);     keyThree.setOnClickListener(this); 
        keyFour.setOnClickListener(this);    keyFive.setOnClickListener(this);     keySix.setOnClickListener(this);     
        keySeven.setOnClickListener(this);    keyEight.setOnClickListener(this);  keyNine.setOnClickListener(this);    
        keySubtract.setOnClickListener(this);   keyHash.setOnClickListener(this);  keyDel.setOnClickListener(this);



}

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        //created a new string object
        String str=new String();
        int click=0;
        int q=0;


        switch(arg0.getId()){   

        //what happens when hash button is pressed

        case R.id.keypad_hash:


            if ("2+3=5".equals(display.getText().toString()))
            {
                correct.setText("CORRECT");
                click=1;
            }

            else if (click==1 && q==1 && "CORRECT".equals(display1.getText().toString()))

            {
                fnum0=(int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));
                snum0=(int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10)));

                int operation = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10 )));

                if(operation == 0)
                    str = fnum0+ "+" + snum0+ "=" + ((fnum0+snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                else if(operation == 1)
                    str = fnum0+ "-" + snum0+ "=" + ((fnum0+snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                else if(operation == 2)
                    str = fnum0+ "*" + snum0+ "=" + ((fnum0+snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                else if(operation == 0)
                    str = fnum0+ "/" + snum0+ "=" + ((fnum0+snum0<10)? "?" : "??");
                display.setText(str);
                             display.setText(fnum0+"+"+snum0+"=");

                             click=2;

             }

        case R.id.keypad_1:

            String str1 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str1.replace("?", "1"));  
        break; 



        case R.id.keypad_2:
            String str2 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str2.replace("?", "2"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_3:
            String str3 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str3.replace("?", "3"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_4:
            String str4 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str4.replace("?", "4"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_5:
            String str5 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str5.replace("?", "5"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_6:
            String str6 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str6.replace("?", "6"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_7:
            String str7 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str7.replace("?", "7"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_8:
            String str8 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str8.replace("?", "8"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_9:
            String str9 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str9.replace("?", "9"));
            break;


        case R.id.keypad_0:
            String str0 = display.getText().toString();  
            display.setText(str0.replace("?", "0"));
            break;

        case R.id.keypad_subtract:
        display.setText("-");
        break;
        }
    }

    public void requestFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an new method specific `click` on every button press.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) { 

    //created a new string object 
    String str=new String(); 
    int click=0;  /// <----  here
    int q=0;
```

This is what is being reference and will never increment between method calls.

Comment: i changed from "click=1" to "click=0" in every button press but still not getting any random expression

Comment: You need to remove this line althogether, and reset `click = 0` when you actually want to do it.

Comment: when i remove that line  it comes up with error saying "create a  local variable int click = 0 in the IF statement" which means that it not allowing me to use "click = 0" in the If statement unless i declare and intialize it

Comment: Had anothwr read, the problem is you are setting `click=1` in the first `if`, then trying to read it in the second `if` but that is an `else if` so will be ignored.  Just remove the `else`.